# remap apostrophe to other keys using hammerspoon

Tags: hammerspoon

the problem is caused by library's bug and this had been fixed.

---

I'm using hammerspoon and I'm trying to remap `Ctrl + '` to backtick(`) but I cannot.

the setting file init.lua is like below:

```
local function keyCode(key, modifiers)
   modifiers = modifiers or {}
   return function()
      hs.eventtap.event.newKeyEvent(modifiers, string.lower(key), true):post()
      hs.timer.usleep(100)
      hs.eventtap.event.newKeyEvent(modifiers, string.lower(key), false):post()
   end
end

local function remapKey(modifiers, key, keyCode)
   hs.hotkey.bind(modifiers, key, keyCode, nil, keyCode)
end

remapKey({'ctrl'}, 'h', keyCode('delete')) // works
remapKey({'ctrl'}, "'", keyCode("`")) // does not work
```

error message is:

```
Invalid key: ' - this may mean that the key requested does not exist in your keymap (particularly if you switch keyboard layouts frequently)
```

it seems the problem is `hs.keycodes.map` does not include apostrophe (but it includes double-quote and backtick).

is it possible to remap apostrophe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point here is the keyboard layout (that Hammerspoon thinks your keyboard is in).

Do you actually have an apostrophe (<kbd>`</kbd>) key on your keyboard?
I mean, if you need to type something like <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>@</kbd> to input the apostrophe, then you must tell so to `newKeyEvent`.

```
remapKey({'ctrl'}, "'", keyCode("@", {"shift"}))
```

Or, you could simply use hs.eventtap.keyStroke() in the keyCode() function if you don't want to bother with how to type a string using the keyboard:

```
local function keyCode(key, modifiers)
   modifiers = modifiers or {}
   return function()
      hs.eventtap.keyStroke(modifiers, key)
   end
end
```

As for `hs.keycodes.map` having the double quote instead of the single quote, it turned out to be a bug of Hammerspoon, so I've just filed a [PR](https://github.com/Hammerspoon/hammerspoon/pull/1332).

Comment: thank you for your answer.
My keyboard layout is US and I've not changed it, so I should be able to use single quote and backtick.

also thank you for your finding that there is a bug related to this. I'm waiting for the fix to be released.

Comment: Try `39` (or `0x27`) instead of `"'"` for now, you don't have to wait for a new release.

Comment: The PR above has been merged, and 0.9.53 will ship with the fix.